# Calculate the line integral

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

Calculate 
$\int_{|z|=1}{\frac{|dz|}{|z-c|^2}}$ when $|c|<1$.
I've tried to substitute $z$ for $e^{i\theta}$ and somehow use the fact that on the unit circle $\overline{z}=\frac{1}{z}$ but I have not found the way to use it.
I would like a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on a good way. Note that $\lvert dz\rvert = d\theta = \frac{dz}{iz}$ if you use $z = e^{i\theta}$, and use your observation $\overline{z} = \frac{1}{z}$ on the unit circle to obtain

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{\lvert dz\rvert}{\lvert z-c\rvert^2} = \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{1}{(z-c)\left(\frac{1}{z}-\overline{c}\right)} \frac{dz}{iz}.$$

It should be doable from then on.